# Getting a value from request, django

Tags: python, django, request, django-filter

I am trying to get a value from `request` and really suprised an error is being raised.

```
def product_view(request):
    lookup_type_user = request.GET.get('lookup_type', '')

    LOOKUP_TYPE_CHOICES = (
                ('gt', '>'),
                ('lt', '<'),    
              )

    class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        lookup_type = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=LOOKUP_TYPE_CHOICES)
        price = django_filters.NumberFilter(lookup_type=lookup_type_user)
```

This line, being basically the same, works fine.

```
price = django_filters.NumberFilter(lookup_type='gte')
```

I am not posting the error message because it's a package relevant one and since the line above where I provided `lookup_type` by hand did not raise anything I am assumming it has nothing to do with that package but the code above.

Can you see what goes wrong here?

**@EDIT**

Is there a way I can print out the `request` to see what it contains exactly?

Comment: Where is this code? Presumably it's not all together in one place. Or are you really defining the ProductFilter inside the view function?

Comment: `lookup_type_user` is evaluated once when you import this file. I'm assuming you get an error like "request doesn't exist" or so?

Comment: What is the URL? Is `'>'` is passed appropriately?

Comment: Daniel, it's in `views.py`. I did not know how to use this package django-filter otherwise to supply it with this request value I am getting, so I figured out put all the code in views.

Comment: URL is probably fine: `&lookup_type=gte&`; I get an error like `data must be QuerySet-like (have count and order_by) or support list(data)` it's django_tables2 specific.

Comment: @nutship that didn't answer the question. Are you defining the filter inside your view *function*? If not, where are you getting `lookup_type_user` from?

Comment: Oh yes. It's all inside one function.

Comment: I edited my question, would you have a look please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. It was my ignorance. I had to redefine `lookup_type` in `forms.py` instead. Like this:

```
lookup_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LOOKUP_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

and not:

```
lookup_type = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=LOOKUP_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Because what django-filter was doing, it was trying to filter the `lookup_type` field, which does not exist in my models. It was throwing an error `FieldError at/. Cannot resolve keyword 'lookup_type' into field`, which I did not know about because another app I am using - django_tables2 modified this error to something else, which tricked me successfully.

It's probably a useless thread now but I just want to let pleople who tried to solve this, know.